# angular: using restmod as an alternative to restangular for rest operations

Tags: angularjs, restangular

https://github.com/platanus/angular-restmod seems much clearer to me than restangular but I can't find much info about it - has anyone used it, know of any pitfalls, etc.?
For instance, I can't see support for PATCH for partial updates.  Any and all info is welcome.

Comment: PATCH support is planned for 1.1

Comment: Yeah, saw that in "issues" but couldn't find the roadmap schedule anywhere...

Comment: Old post, but I stumbled across this in my searches and thought I'd add my observation. "Restmod brings Rails ActiveRecord's ease of use to the Angular Framework." One nice thing about restangular is it *avoids* ActiveRecord, or any other ORMish anti-pattern.

Comment: PATCH supported for a while now

Answer (score 3):

We are using [Angular Restmod](https://github.com/platanus/angular-restmod) in various projects in production and I can tell you it does what it says it does.

Take a look at the issues in Github, there's a lot going on there right now.

Comment: Do you have any experience of using restmod with jsonapi.org 1.0 standard? I am looking for style packer for jsonapi.org standard